# How can I make Vuze work with Lion? (It cannot transfer any data)

Tags: macos, java

I'm having a bit of trouble with Vuze after installing 10.7 (and the JRE.)
Vuze can connect to seeds and peers, but no data will transfer! That makes it a bit useless.

So far I have tried:

- Running Vuze as root
- Switching to the 32 bit JRE
- Trying the 4.2.0.5 Vuze beta
- Attempting to run it using the Java 1.7 OpenJRE (wouldn't launch.)
- Attempting to install the Leopard Java 1.5 JRE (wouldn't install.)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I recommend Transmission over Vuze any day. It works fine on Lion and is way way better in my opinion. Free as well.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, Mac OSX Lion has issues with java.

I'm pretty sure this is a Java issue. Apple's support for Java in 10.7 is severely lacking. I had to download (wasn't installed with 10.7) Java 1.6.0_24 using Apple's ADC (developer) site.

Installed Java and restarted my Mac. Launched Vuze and I was able to receive incoming traffic. Paused the download and it all ended there. Vuze now keeps crashing and I'm still not receiving any incoming traffic again.

Source: http://forum.vuze.com/thread.jspa?threadID=96592

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Vuze, so I can't comment on that, but I can help you get Java 1.5 running on Lion.  I used to have to do that for Zend Studio 5.x.  To install J2SE 5.0 on Lion follow the instructions here: http://www.s-seven.net/java_15_lion